# To add div scroll bar into window scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the above link,I want to make the single scroll bar(window scroll bar) without changing the height of the div.container using js and jquery.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid      ipsam         nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.
              </p>
         </div>
        <div class="container2">
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel ullam saepe qui dolorum, repudiandae sed, consequatur pariatur. Accusantium sint, temporibus, nisi quis, perspiciatis voluptate neque ducimus aperiam est fuga atque.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ipsam nam suscipit non tempore, reprehenderit totam ea dicta, incidunt, repudiandae natus cupiditate fugit aperiam eveniet quasi deserunt, nulla itaque quo.</p>
             </div>
```

CSS:

```
   .container {
        width:100%;
        height:200px;
        background-color:#333;
        color:#fff;
        overflow:auto;
    }
```

Comment: *In the above link* where is link?

Comment: No need for `Lorem ipsum` texts.. Just describe your problem good as possible and you won't get the error for adding more characters to your post.

Comment: Umm... either lose the CSS `height` property, or make it `overflow: hidden;`. If neither of those are a suitable solution, then I'm afraid you've not described what you _want_ to happen well enough.